# Jquery error when binding menu item with scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, navigation

I try to bind navigation menu with scrolling. the effect: when I scroll the window browser, the active menu item will highlight.

this is the html:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#intro">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#anchor5">Link 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost/pages/blog/">BLOG</a></li>
</ul>
```

the jquery code is:

```
$(window).load(function(){
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $(".navigation"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

this error appear on the firbug console:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://localhost/pages/blog/
```

I figure out that the code does not handle the abslolute url:

```
var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
```

then I replaced it with:

```
var item = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
```

Now this error has shown:

```
    TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined
if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
```

Note, when I remove the html line :

```
<li><a href="http://localhost/pages/blog/">BLOG</a></li>
```

every thing going well. but with it, those error happened, and the menu scrolling affect does not take place.

Do you have any clue, where is the problem? and how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you setup fiddle, and/or provide css and the rest of html?

Comment: @nevermind I use firebug.. I've inserted the related html, the rest is very long, contains many sections, each section has ID. about css it is just to change the active class's color.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of searching and trying to understand where is the problem, I solve it.( please refer to this page [as the resource of my solution](http://dolinked.com/questions/1362007/scrollspy-effect-stopped-working)

replace this code in jquery:

```
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
  var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
  if (item.length) { return item; }
});
```

with this code:

```
// Anchors corresponding to menu items
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){

  var indexItm = $(this).attr('href').indexOf('#');
  if (indexItm >= 0) {
    var str = $(this).attr('href').substring(indexItm);
    var item = $(str);
    if (item.length) { return item; }
    }
})
;
```

that's all.

> var item = $($(this).attr("href")); in code was creating problem because when you write href="#id" it is var item = $(#id); but when you write href="/blog/" it becomes var item = $(/blog/); which is incorrect.